# Does some components search by specs encyclopedia exist?

Tags: components

I'm wondering if exists some comprehensive search resource where I could find electrical components parts (resistances, inductors, diodes, capacitors, transistors etc. etc.) of most producers and related specs. 
For example, consider that you need a 1 farad capacitor, you may just start to google *"1 farad capacitors"* and start to check the detailed specs of each producer, and this is time consuming.

Would be better if you can have a service where you can search *"1 farad capacitor"* check (almost) all the models present on the market to choose the one with desired thermal tolerance and better shelf life, a specific material etc. using a detailed contextually parametrized search.

Something similar would be very useful also to do comparison based on average price to design products with a better quality\price ratio.

I'm doing this question because I'm considering to create a similar service.

Comment: Distributors provide that service for free, and include pricing and availability in real-time.  Not sure what you could add to that.

Comment: Yes, there are. digikey.com, mouser.com, newark.com, probably others I'm not aware of too.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I suppose the distributor provides the service for product that It distribute and I doubt includes detailed market statistics and data others than the ones strictly needed to sold them. Am I wrong?

Comment: Market statistics would be their proprietary data to the extent they collect them. There are market research firms who prepare expensive reports but I have my doubts as to the accuracy as most large quantity deals are done with closely-held negotiated price and terms, and they tend to ignore lesser-known (particularly offshore) players who may be doing enormous volume. That's more-or-less intentional because they're gathering information for companies that are looking to measure their market share against peer competitors.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.siliconexpert.com/

Here you can find (probably) all the electronics parts with there respective electrical parameters, cost and you can compare similar parts from different manufacture.

You can get free trial for few days.

Comment: thanks I will give a check